# Opening Office Documents in Visual Studio Solution Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to directly open an Office document that's in a Visual Studio solution folder? Double-clicking the file does nothing.

In VS Team System 2008 Development Edition, you can right-click on the solution folder and select the 'Open Folder in Windows Explorer' option. Then the file can be opended by double-clicking it, but that seems a bit round about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to open any file type from within Visual Studio that doesn't have a default type associated with it (from within VS), then **nothing** happens. If that is the case, then

- right click the file and select "Open With ..."
- choose the application you'd like to open that file type with, and
- select the "Set as Default" option button.

Files of that type can now be opened directly within VS.